# How to replace Windows 8 with Ubuntu on an Acer ES1-711 laptop?

Tags: boot, windows

I want to know how to disable the secure boot sequence to allow Ubuntu or Linux Mint to replace Windows 8 completely on my Acer 64 bit laptop.

Comment: You mean you have already dual boot? Try [GParted](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted/)

Answer (score 0):

Your UEFI boot enabled BIOS has a way of entering setup.  To do this simply hit F2 or F8 to access your Firmware BIOS.  Now you will find the boot tab and shuffle your way over to it.  Now I am not certain how your setup will be, but my dell has it as a single item that can be changed to enable or disable.  If it is not its own option look under either UEFI Mode or Boot Mode.  Once you change that shuffle to the exit tab and select save changes and reboot/exit/shutdown.

Comment: Already tried that. I am familiar with the basics, unfortunately this configuration has me stumped. It continues to fail.

Comment: Your boot sequence is out of order let me setup my Acer and get back to you

Comment: Your USB FDD should be number 1.  Since my Acer doesnt have Secure Boot, and you did disable it I hope already.  @JamesPhipps